# Angular 2 cannot read property using Interface

Tags: angular, interface

I've got some troubles with interface, when I try to use my function, console throws an error: error_handler.js:55 EXCEPTION: Error in package:355:100:20 caused by: Cannot read property 'registerStudent' of undefined
it's my interface:

```
export interface StorageInterface{
registerStudent(obj: StudentRegistrationDTO);}
```

ApiStorage:

```
import { StorageInterface } from './storage.interface';


export class ApiStorage implements StorageInterface{
registerStudent(obj){
        console.log('after');
        }
}
```

My DTO:

```
import { ApiStorage} from '../api.storage';
export class StudentRegistrationDTO{
private apiStorage: ApiStorage;
constructor(
    private firstName: string
){} 
registerStudentDTO(){
            console.log('before');
            this.apiStorage.registerStudent(this);
    }
```

and my component file:

```
import { StudentRegistrationDTO } from '../storage/dto/registration.student.dto';
export class StudentRegisterComponent {
sRDTO: StudentRegistrationDTO;
 send(){
        this.sRDTO = new StudentRegistrationDTO(
            this.service.first_name)

    this.sRDTO.registerStudentDTO();
        }
}
```

Do you know maybe what's going on here ? Why does it throw error?
Console print "before" and then throw error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you didn't instantiate your `apiStorage` varaible. Try this for your DTO :

```
import { ApiStorage} from '../api.storage';
export class StudentRegistrationDTO{
private apiStorage: ApiStorage;
constructor(
    private firstName: string
){
    this.apiStorage = new ApiStorage(/* any object that suits your constructor */);
} 
registerStudentDTO(){
            console.log('before');
            this.apiStorage.registerStudent(this);
    }
```